# How to use neural voices in Azure Direct Line Speech bot

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to update the experimental [DirectLineSpeech Echo Bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/directline-speech/csharp_dotnetcore/02.echo-bot/Bots/EchoBot.cs)'s `Speak()` method to use neural voices, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the code I am trying to make it work -

```
public IActivity Speak(string message)
{
    var activity = MessageFactory.Text(message);
    string body = @"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>
        <voice name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaNeural)'>
        <mstts:express-as type='chat'>" + $"{message}" + "</mstts:express-as></voice></speak>";
    activity.Speak = body;
    return activity;
}
```

This is based on the recommendation provided in the [SSML Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup#adjust-speaking-styles)

Here's the standard T2S for reference:

```
public IActivity Speak(string message)
{
    var activity = MessageFactory.Text(message);
    string body = @"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>
        <voice name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'>" +
        $"{message}" + "</voice></speak>";
    activity.Speak = body;
    return activity;
}
```

Can someone help me understand how does it work or what am I doing wrong?

If it helps find any restrictions, I have deployed the bot as app service in F1 free tier in westus2 region.

Edit: Updated the code to use the full name ie. `Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaNeural)` instead of the short name `en-US-JessaNeural` as suggested by Nicholas. But this doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Neural voice exact name is `Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaNeural)`. But the main thing is that you wanted to use a speaking style, using `mstts:express-as`.

The thing is that you forgot to add the block declaring `mstts` namespace in the xml (`xmlns:mstts='https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts'`):

```
"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <voice name='en-US-JessaNeural'>
        <mstts:express-as type='chat'>" + $"{message}" + "</mstts:express-as>
    </voice>
</speak>";
```

Should be:

```
"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='https://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xmlns:mstts='https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts' xml:lang='en-US'>
    <voice name='en-US-JessaNeural'>
        <mstts:express-as type='chat'>" + $"{message}" + "</mstts:express-as>
    </voice>
</speak>";
```

Comment: I had tried that as well and it still doesn't work. The voice name I used is the short name which should also work.

Comment: If it helps, my bot is deployed as app service in free tier and is in westus2 region.

Comment: The DLS Client Sample App never receives Connector_ActivityReceived event after the speech has been recognized and I get this Connector_Recognized event.

Comment: I will try to have a look in details to the sample app you are mentioning

Comment: I successfully got the neural voice when implementing it without the `mstts:express-as` field. With this field, I did not get the voice output and I got a strange behavior in the output, with the echo reply followed by the welcome message

Comment: So I can confirm that it works without custom expression but no with it, there may be a bug or incompatibility here

Comment: Ok, I got it!! After getting this behaviour, I directly tested Neural speech using `mstts:express-as`, which pointed me to the error. You forgot to add `xmlns:mstts="https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts"` in the request to declare mstts namespace. Reply edited, have fun

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!!